# How to use GroupBy, Buffer and Scan/Reduce in the same RxJava query

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java3

I have an infinite stream of data coming from my application. The event data looks like this:

```java
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Event {
  String Name;
  String Type;
  String Value;
}
```

In order for me to most efficiently drive my target API I need to do the following:

- Group all the incoming `Event`s by `Name` and `Type`.
- Reduce the Grouped events to target the following structure (Where the `OrdinalValues` and `OrdinalCounts` are a lossless summary of the original data):

```java
@Builder
@ToString
public class ApiEvent {
    String Name;
    String Type;
    Collection<String> OrdinalValues;
    Collection<Integer> OrdinalCounts;
}
```

- Collect up to 1000 of the reduced events for up to 60 seconds.
- Call my API with the collection of `ApiEvent`s.

Using RxJava 3 I came up with the following:

```java
PublishProcessor<Event> publishProcessor = PublishProcessor.create();
TestSubscriber<List<ApiEvent>> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();

publishProcessor
        .groupBy(event -> Event.builder().Name(event.Name).Type(event.Type).build())
        .flatMap(x -> x.scan(new Hashtable<>(), this::reduceEvents)
                .map(a -> (ApiEvent.builder()
                                .Name(x.getKey().Name)
                                .Type(x.getKey().Type)
                                .OrdinalValues(a.keySet())
                                .OrdinalCounts(a.values())
                                .build()
                        )
                )
        )
        .buffer(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler, 1000)
        .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
        .flatMap((List<ApiEvent> x) -> {

            val grp = x.stream()
                    .collect(groupingBy(post -> Pair.of(post.Name, post.Type)));

            val reducedData = new ArrayList<ApiEvent>(grp.size());

            grp.keySet().forEach(key -> grp.get(key).stream()
                    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.OrdinalCounts.size()))
                    .map(reducedData::add));

            return Flowable.fromArray(reducedData);
        })
        .subscribe(testSubscriber);

publishProcessor.onNext(Event.builder().Name("Name1").Type("Type1").Value("Value1").build());
publishProcessor.onNext(Event.builder().Name("Name1").Type("Type1").Value("Value1").build());
publishProcessor.onNext(Event.builder().Name("Name2").Type("Type2").Value("Value2").build());
publishProcessor.onNext(Event.builder().Name("Name2").Type("Type2").Value("Value2").build());

testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

testSubscriber.assertValueCount(1);

testSubscriber.values().forEach(a -> {
    System.out.println(a);
    // Result: [
    //    ApiEvent(Name=Name2, Type=Type2, OrdinalValues=[Value2], OrdinalCounts=[2]),
    //    ApiEvent(Name=Name1, Type=Type1, OrdinalValues=[Value1], OrdinalCounts=[2])
    // ]
});
```

(For completeness the reduce function is:)

```java
private Hashtable<String, Integer> reduceEvents(Hashtable<String, Integer> hashtable,
                                                    Event event) {
    if (hashtable.containsKey(event.Value))) {
        hashtable.replace(event.Value, hashtable.get(event.Value) + 1);
    } else {
        hashtable.put(event.Value, 1D);
    }
    return hashtable;
}
```

which gives me my expected behavior. However, because I have to use `scan` rather than `reduce`, I have to reprocess the "chatty" output to pick a single `ApiEvent` to represent the aggregated data. This seems wasteful, but no matter what I've tried I can't get `reduce` to work as I expect.

Is this the best I can do?